# Countdown timer Help

Tags: ios4

Hey I was wondering if someone could help me.  I am pretty new to Xcode but anyways I wondered if someone could help me with a code.  I want to be able to put a timer on that will disable the phones password for the selected period of time.  Once the timer ends the password will then be enabled again.  If someone could help me out that would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

guess that won't be possible since even in iphone-sdk-4 there only some limited instructions you could do while your program is sleeping (another proram is active) and I don't think there is a way to disable password checking to begin with.